# CSS underline menu item

Tags: css

Hi So I am using the following for underlines on hover. However, I can not figure out what to use to get the same line in the same position on active.

```
.cool-link::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 3px;
    background: #f83269;
    transition: width .3s;
    margin-top: 18px;
    
}

.cool-link:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an `active` class :

```css
.cool-link:hover::after,
.cool-link.active::after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

If you mean the [`:active` CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) :

```css
.cool-link:hover::after,
.cool-link:active::after {
    width: 100%;
}
```